# Ошибка отправки POST-запроса из формы

Tags: post, html, php

```
<form action="/get_post.php" method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='test.t' value='test'>
    <input type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

get_post.php

```
<?php
   echo "test->".$_POST[test.t];
?>
```

Почему то get_post.php не выдает, не отвечает. Не могу разобраться, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP автоматически переводит символ '.' в названии переменной полученной через POST или GET  в символ '_'.
ПОэтому вы можете в сценарии получить значение вот так

```
 <?php
       echo "test->".$_POST['test_t'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Ale_x, спасибо огромное. теперь все работает.

Comment: Да не во что ;)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `$_POST['test.t']`
Т.е. ассоциативный индекс закавычить.

Comment: Я тут забыл написать `$_POST['test.t']`. E меня в форме так оно и есть. Просто тут когда в `<input type='hidden' name='test.t' value='test'>` и `$_POST[test.t]` убираю точку. Все нормально работает. Тут проблема в точке. А я хочу написать с точкой. Как это сделать?